# python 2.7 windows ImportError: No module named OpenSSL

Tags: python-2.7, module, openssl

I try to make https server on windows using python 2.7, and [this is](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442473-simple-http-server-supporting-ssl-secure-communica/) my source. when i run it i got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "httpserver.py", line 38, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL
ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
```

Do i need to install that module first or is it default installed on my system?
Or maybe is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install the OpenSSL modue.

Python uses below search path in sequence to find the module you are trying to import:

1. The home directory of the program
2. Diretories in environment variable PYTHONPATH
3. Standard library diretories
4. The contents of any .pth files

I guess the python program won't find anything in item 1 and 2 above.

So, try to check the standard library directories by using below:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

It will return the paths to the standard library directories. Just check in those directories and if you don't see OpenSSL, then yes, you have to install the module first.